# Output JXA to stdout

Tags: javascript, javascript-automation

I have a small script made with JXA (JavaScript for Automation) that outputs a result to the shell with `console.log`.

However, `console.log` seems to output to stderr and I’d like to output to stdout. I can always `2>&1` when calling the script, but it would be preferable to output directly to stdout from the script.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Close voters: This question on-topic since scripting is specifically listed as being on-topic on this site.

Comment: How are you writing to console.log surely you are writing to stdout or stderr

Comment: @Mark Just `console.log('whatever')`. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Wgat does the documentation for console.log say?

Comment: @Mark I never found any official good documentation on JXA. You can’t really deduce this one, though. I don’t have a problem building scripts, I’m asking for the specific function (or option) that’ll do what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution: don’t use `console.log` or anything else. Instead of

```
console.log('something');
```

Simply

```
'something';
```

It will be output to stdout.

Comment: Only returns last statement

Comment: @basil As would be expected.

Comment: But what character encoding will be used?

Answer (score 4):

It may not be the prettiest solution ever, but I think your best bet is to use the Objective-C scripting bridge. The alternative would be to deal directly with the command line and `printf`, which would probably be even messier.

Using the scripting bridge, you can re-assign `console.log` to a custom function that writes to `stdout` using `NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardOutput`. If you put this definition at the top of your program, you can then use this revised `console.log`.

```
console.log = function() {
    ObjC.import('Foundation');
    for (argument of arguments) {
        $.NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardOutput.writeData($.NSString.alloc.initWithString(String(argument) + "\n").dataUsingEncoding($.NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding));
    }
}
```

Note that I've added a line break at the end of each string—you may want to customize this behavior to meet your needs.

Comment: Grate! But some data should be unwrapped before output: `console.log(ObjC.unwrap(app.bundleIdentifier)) `